# How to print multiple input's output in python

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of User:\n"))
for i in range(0,n):
    print("Enter the details of User %d"%(i+1))
    name=input("Enter the name of the user:\n")
    mno=int(input("Enter the mobile number of the user:\n"))
    uname=input("Enter the username of the user:\n")
    pswd=input("Enter the password of the user:\n")
```

I'm having trouble printing this code
How to print output of this code**

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want to accomplish and what is the problem with your current code? Try to make a clear example of the expected behaviour if you cannot describe it well.

Comment: What do you think "the output of this code" means? Can you show an example of **exactly** what the user might type, and **exactly** what should be printed as a result?

Answer (score 3):

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of User:\n"))
output=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    print("Enter the details of User %d"%(i+1))
    name=input("Enter the name of the user:\n")
    mno=int(input("Enter the mobile number of the user:\n"))
    uname=input("Enter the username of the user:\n")
    pswd=input("Enter the password of the user:\n")
    output.append({
       "name":name,
       "mno":mno,
       "uname":uname,
       "pswd":pswd
    })
print(output)
```

## output

```
Enter the number of User:
1
Enter the details of User 1
Enter the name of the user:
reza
Enter the mobile number of the user:
1212
Enter the username of the user:
rb
Enter the password of the user:
23232
```

## [{'name': 'reza', 'mno': 1212, 'uname': 'rb', 'pswd': '23232'}]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to accumulate user data so you can print all of it at the end (if this is not true, you can just add a line `print(f"User {i+1} is named {name} with mobile number {mno} (username {uname}, password {pswd}")` at the bottom of the for loop. I think there are two approaches here, one of which will serve you better. The worse but simpler approach is to store each data point as an individual array:

```py
name = []
mno = []
uname = []
pswd = []
n=int(input("Enter the number of User:\n"))
for i in range(0,n):
    print("Enter the details of User %d"%(i+1))
    name.append(input("Enter the name of the user:\n"))
    mno.append(int(input("Enter the mobile number of the user:\n")))
    uname.append(input("Enter the username of the user:\n"))
    pswd.append(input("Enter the password of the user:\n"))
print(f"names: {name}\nPhone Numbers: {mno}\nUsernames: {uname}, Password: {pswd}")
# This information could be processed later in the program with name[0], mno[0]
```

The better alternative is to use Python's OOP model and create a User class with an `__init__` which would set internal variables respective to the name, mno, uname, pswd as input, store it in `self`, and allow you to just write `print(user)` if you added a `__repr__` or `__str__` interface in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

````
input_data = []
for i in range(0, n):
    print("Enter the details of User %d" % (i + 1))
    name = input("Enter the name of the user:\n")
    mno = int(input("Enter the mobile number of the user:\n"))
    uname = input("Enter the username of the user:\n")
    pswd = input("Enter the password of the user:\n")

    input_data.append({
        "name": name,
        "mno": mno,
        "uname": uname,
        "pswd": pswd,
    })

print(input_data)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of User:\n"))
name_lst = []
mno_lst = []
uname_lst = []
pswd_lst = []
for i in range(0,n):
    print("Enter the details of User %d"%(i+1))
    name=input("Enter the name of the user:\n")
    name_lst.append(name)
    mno=int(input("Enter the mobile number of the user:\n"))
    mno_lst.append(mno)
    uname=input("Enter the username of the user:\n")
    uname_lst.append(uname)
    pswd=input("Enter the password of the user:\n")
    pswd_lst.append(pswd)

name = iter(name_lst)
mno = iter(mno_lst)
uname = iter(uname_lst) 
pswd = iter(pswd_lst)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print("Details of User : ",i)
    print("The Name Of User Is : ",next(name))
    print("The Mobile Number Of User Is : ",next(mno))
    print("The User Name Of User Is : ",next(uname))
    print("The Password Of User Is : ",next(pswd))
    print()
```